# Should we enable CDN for a single live stream for 10,000 geographically spread users?

Tags: cdn, live-streaming, azure-media-services

Trying to understand the benefits of CDN for a live company-wide town meeting.  I understand how it would help for Azure blob streaming, but what about live video?  If there's nothing to cache does a CDN offer any benefit?

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of a CDN is content distribution over a large geographic area. If you are expecting viewers to come from all over the world then having a CDN would enable your content to be delivered from a closer location to that user.

It could have benefits for you even locally as well depending where you are. Some areas have a few Azure regions near them so it may well provide some benefit there.

One thing for certain is that you won't see a performance hit by using a CDN. Ultimately it's down to if the Azure Streaming Endpoint could support 10,000 viewers or if you'll need to CDN back it, I've done live streaming to more than that before without a CDN before the integration existed and it was fine **but** I would personally still look to make use of the CDN.

You can find more details on it over in this [Getting Started](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/getting-started-with-live-streaming-using-the-azure-management-portal/) blog post.